# Select each TXT1 From xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a xml structure like

```
<TT TXT1="Mouse"/><TT TXT1="Computer"/><TT TXT1="Electronics"/>
```

I want to select each TXT1 from this xml.I tried some code .my code is like

```
<xsl:variable name="category" select="cate.xml"/>
<xsl value-of select ="$category/TT/TXT1"/>
```

But I didn't get the answer. Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:variable name="cat-doc" select="document('cate.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="txt1-atts" select="$cat-doc//TT/@TXT1"/>
```

should allow you to select all `TXT1` attributes of all `TT` elements in the document `cate.xml`.

If you then want to output those attribute values then in XSLT 2.0 it suffices to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$txt1-atts" separator=", "/>
```

with XSLT 1.0 however you need

```
<xsl:for-each select="$txt1-atts">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I need to get the last value first, to a variable.and second to another and first to another variable.

<xsl:variable name="first " select="TXT1(Electronics)">